# 2002 Dodge Stratus loses all electric power after jump starting and running a few minutes

Tags: electrical

Already replaced the alternator and battery.  Alternator is putting out 13.7 volts and battery is reading 14.1.  I jumped the battery and starts right up, but after removing jumper cables the dash lights begin to flicker and then after a few minutes the car loses all electrical power.  I am at a loss of what could be causing this since the alternator and battery are working fine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Need more information. Was the battery reading 14.1 V with or without the jumper cables? If it was 14.1 V with the jumper cables, it would indicate that the battery is not getting charged by the alternator.

Answer (score 2):

The key bit of information missing from the question is whether the battery was reading 14.1 V with or without the jumper cables.

If the reading was taken with the jumper cables on the battery, it would indicate that the battery is not getting charged by the alternator when the jumper cables are removed.

This could be due to:

- a break in the battery-charging ciruit
- battery terminal corrosion
- a bad wire in the battery-charging circuit

Answer (score 0):

check the amp for the radio under passenger seat, it gets moist, rust and curotion shorts out, causing electrical problems and car while die when driving. M.HOWARD